# push object originally on the stack to a vector, will the objects get lost?

Tags: vector, stl, heap-memory, stack-memory

I just started using STL, say I have a rabbit class, now I'm creating a rabbit army...

```
#include <vector>

vector<rabbit> rabbitArmy (numOfRabbits,rabbit()); 
//Q1: these rabbits are on the heap right?

rabbit* rabbitOnHeap = new rabbit(); 
//Q2: rabbitOnHeap is on the heap right?

rabbit rabbitOnStack; 
//Q3: this rabbit is on the stack right?

rabbitArmy.push_back(rabbitOnStack); 
//Q4: rabbitOnStack will remain stored on the stack? 
//And it will be deleted automatically, though it's put in the rabbitArmy now?
```

Q4 is the one I'm most concerned with, should I always use ***new*** keyword to add rabbit to my army?

Q5: Is there better way to add rabbits to the army than:

```
rabbitArmy.push_back(*rabbitOnHeap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since you haven't specified otherwise, the objects you put in the vector will be allocated with `std::allocator<rabbit>`, which uses `new`. For what it's worth, that's *usually* called the "free store" rather than the heap<sup>1</sup>.
2. Again, the usual term is the free store.
3. Officially, that's "automatic storage", but yes, on your typical implementation that'll be the stack, and on an implementation that doesn't support a stack in hardware, it'll still be a stack-like (LIFO) data structure of some sort.
4. When you add an item to a vector (or other standard container) what's actually added to the container is a *copy* of the item you pass as a parameter. The item you pass as a parameter remains yours to do with as you please. In the case of something with automatic storage class, it'll be destroyed when it goes out of scope -- but the copy of it in the collection will remain valid until it's erased or the collection destroyed, etc.
5. No. In fact, you should only rarely use `new` to allocate items you're going to put in a standard collection. Since the item in the array will be a copy of what you pass, you don't normally need to use `new` to allocate it.
6. Usually you just push back a local object.

For example:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    rabbitArmy.push_back(rabbit());
```

This creates 10 temporary `rabbit` objects (the `rabbit()` part), adds a copy of each to the rabbitArmy. Then each of the temporaries is destroyed, but the copies of them in the rabbitArmy remain.

---

1. In typical usage, "the heap" refers to memory managed by `calloc`, `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free`. What `new` and `delete` manage is the free store. A new expression, in turn, obtains memory from an `operator new` (either global or inside a class). `operator new` and `operator delete` are specified so they *could* be almost a direct pass-through to `malloc` and `free` respectively, but even when that's the case the heap and free store are normally thought of separately.